# Как быть с waypoint и ajax load more?

Tags: javascript

есть такая проблема. Waypoint js видит лишь те элементы что подгрузились изначально. А как сделать что бы он видел элементы что подгрузились ajax ом после?

Comment: что значет "видит"? покажите код, где не видит